# What would it be like if earth became flat?

Tags: science-based, humans, science-fiction, life

Suppose suddenly earth become flat one day how would it affect us as we are used to the round earth.

Not a flat-earther just a doubt

Comment: This question is rather broad, but the summary of answers will be:  Every living thing dies horribly as the Earth collapses into a sphere again and completely melts in the process.

Comment: I think some constraints are going to be needed on this question to know what exactly you're asking. For example, a cornerstone of the flat Earth theory is that the Sun moves in a circle above Earth as opposed to the Earth orbiting the Sun. Is this part of your question? That alone would have all sorts of effects on everything and couldn't possibly happen with our current understanding of physics. On the topic of not lining up with physics, I don't think the `science-based` tag is really suitable for this question.

Comment: I agree with Cyrus, as this question is too broad, and could use some narrowing down. Or maybe split it into different questions regarding smaller topics.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming it stayed in such a position, most areas would find themselves perpendicular to gravity (closer to the rim of the disc). Those closer to the centre of the disc would find all of the water in the world rushing in from all directions on the largest recorded tsunami. If you walked from the centre outwards, the ground would become increasingly steep until near vertical (assuming gravity is still centred around the middle of the disc).

in terms of daily life, everything would be pretty much the same with subtle changes (after the world recovers from the tsunami and buildings literally falling off the ground and tumbling towards the centre). For one, farming would mostly occur in Steppes due to the slope of the ground in most areas. Also, the only bodies of water such as oceans and lakes would exist in the centre, with few if not no fresh water available. Close to the rim, vegetation would likely die due to lack of water.

The atmosphere would all be attracted to the centre, leaving the edges of the disc literally in space. The only breathable air would be near the centre, and the separate halves of the planet would experience separate weather patterns and climates due to being completely separated by the disc and effectively existing in two seperate atmospheres.

Answer (score 0):

Flat as in squeezing the air out of a balloon, or flat as in cutting up the balloon an putting it on a desk. Either way, the magma pushed to the surface will kill off nearly all life forms immediately, but in the first case, you have two sides to kill off.